# Capturing Login Output from an SSH Session in Python

Tags: python, ssh

I am looking for a way to capture (and verify) the user login output (i.e. the MOTD located in issues.net) from an ssh session using the subprocess module in Python. I’ve tried several variations of the following but have yet to find a way that traps the desired output without either hanging the session or returning only the passed (i.e. “ls –la”) command’s output. I’m using Python 2.6 and have a requirement to use only the native libraries available at this installation (Red Hat 6.5), so modules such as pexpect are currently unavailable to me.
The code below only returns the “ls –la” output, and not the desired ssh login message. **NOTE:** "testUser" utilizes a PKI, thus obviating the need for handling passwords.

```
loginStr = ['ssh', testUser@someHost, "ls -la"]
p = subprocess.Popen(loginStr, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
    line = p.stdout.readline()
    if not line: break
print line
```

I’ve also tried this with similar outcomes:

```
loginStr = ['ssh', testUser@someHost, 'ls', '-la']
p = subprocess.Popen(loginStr, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
(stdout, stderr) = p.communicate()
print stdout
```

Might queues and threads be a solution?. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: there are python ssh libraries `paramiko.SshClient` comes to mind

Comment: You should put that first set of code into a real code block and fix the indentation.

Comment: I'd love to use paramiko but it's not native to the install

Answer (score 0):

You could be using python expect (pexpect)

Something as follows (replace, host, user, passwd appropriately):

(also, adjust according to the regular expression for the shell prompt)

```
import pexpect

cmd = "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no %s -l %s" % (<host>, <user>)
exp = pexpect.spawn(cmd, timeout=7)
idx = exp.expect('assword:')
nc = exp.sendline(<passwd>)
idx = exp.expect('[\n\r](#|\$) ')
if idx == 0:
    before = exp.before 
    print before
```